# In category counts his item from database table

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

### My model code

how we can call this function in blade.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BasicModel extends Model
{
     public static function get_product_count($id){
        $query = "select COUNT(sub_id) AS count FROM products WHERE products.sub_id = $id";
        print_r($query);
        return $query->row_array();
    }

}
```

### My view.blade.php code

count in foreach loop or show in all category

```
@foreach ($r as $row)
         <li class="grid-item type-rent">
         <div class="property-block"> 
           <a href="#" class="property-featured-image"> <img src="{{ URL::to('/template/images/background-images/sub-category-images/' .$row->sub_cat_images. '')}}" alt=""> <!-- <span class="images-count"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> 2</span> <span class="badges">Rent</span> --> </a>
              <div class="property-info">
                 <h4><a href="#">{{ ucwords(substr($row->sub_cat_name, 0, 22)) }}</a></h4>
                 <span class="location">NYC</span>
                   <div class="price"><strong>Items</strong><span>

                              <!-- start count code from here --> 
                              $data = $this->BasicModel->count {{ ($row->sub_id) }}
                              echo $data['count'];
                             </span></div>
                  </div>

               <!-- <div class="property-amenities clearfix"> <span class="area"><strong>5000</strong>Area</span> <span class="baths"><strong>3</strong>Baths</span> <span class="beds"><strong>3</strong>Beds</span> <span class="parking"><strong>1</strong>Parking</span> </div> -->
         </div>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

### My BasicController Code

```
public function grid(Request $request, $id)
    {  
        if ($id == 1) {
            $r = DB::table('sub_category')->select('*')->where('cat_id', $id)
            ->where('sub_status', '1')->orderBy('sub_id', 'asc')->get();

            $name = DB::table('category')->where('cat_id', $id)->get();

           return view('buy-and-sell/grid', compact('r','name','count'));
        }
```

### image for your help

[image: for help]

### image for your help

problem in this image please solve the problem
[image: for help]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are closing the PHP tag in the wrong place. Change to this:

```
<?php print_r($count);
$data = $this->BasicController->count {{ ($row->sub_id) }}
echo $data['count'];//here is the rightplace to close your PHP ?>
</span></div>
```

All PHP code needs to stay between the `<?php` and `?>`

Looking to your image, apparently, it's printing the $count and then it's printing the plain text , so you have `80$data = ...`

Comment: Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
FatalErrorException in b03ed89d24a29a30947c80500522cb49 line 47:
syntax error, unexpected '{'
in b03ed89d24a29a30947c80500522cb49 line 47

Comment: this count in foreach loop. your code is apply only one category

Answer (score 0):

If you counted your rows in controller by the code below

```
$count = DB::table('products')->where('sub_id', $id)->count();
```

then why wrote so many code in `html` for counting?

Remove all code form counting form your `html` and just use this `{{ $count }}`

Comment: Use the above code and `dd($count);`. See what returns.